# Issue in updating weights in keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras-layer

I want to update the weight (filter data and bias weight) using `layer.set_weight()` but got this error:

> You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "con" with a  weight list of length 3, but the layer was expecting 2 weights.

The code that I used is:

```
w = model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

It returns the following data:

> ```
>  [array([[[[ 7.95478702e-01,  3.62834007e-01,  8.63312304e-01,
>            -2.18138605e-01]],
>
>          [[ 9.54419136e-01,  7.83904433e-01,  2.39170641e-01,
>            -4.93528843e-01]],
>
>          [[ 3.85988206e-01,  9.14532781e-01, -1.05724104e-01,
>            -6.36200011e-01]]],
>
>
>         [[[-2.96189755e-01,  1.04245281e+00, -7.93409765e-01,
>            -5.18380702e-01]],
>
>          [[-1.17103405e-01,  7.04082668e-01, -8.85501146e-01,
>            -4.04743433e-01]],
>
>          [[ 6.19280517e-01,  5.28193831e-01,  6.80770318e-04,
>             2.26266444e-01]]],
>
>
>         [[[-7.70748794e-01,  1.13630258e-01,  2.38650933e-01,
>             6.83022439e-01]],
>
>          [[-4.86002900e-02,  6.83946311e-01,  4.66377288e-01,
>             8.29747736e-01]],
>
>          [[ 7.78391004e-01,  2.00692505e-01,  5.20951033e-01,
>             1.11665785e+00]]]], dtype=float32),
>  array([-0.011733  ,  0.00292955,  0.0021829 ,  0.00517058], dtype=float32)]
> ```

Now I want to modify the weight and bias of this layer using `set_weight()` method. How can I modify it?

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand !
And if possible add your tried code so we can help you.

Comment: i have updated the code and result of that code